# NuGet satellite package not added to the lib of the main package

Tags: localization, nuget, nuget-package, satellite-assembly, nuget-server

I'm trying to create a nuget package for the localization of another package, and I'm following the [satellite package approach](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-localized-packages).

I'm pretty sure to have followed these rules strictly, and the naming conventions as well, but as I download the satellite package from my nuget repo server, it's not adding the expected /it/ folder under the /lib/ folder of the main package.

The main files structure is the following

/lib/net45/myfile.dll

and the satellite package has

/lib/net45/it/myfile.resources.dll

I tried everything, and I double check my packages configurations with the **AspNet.Mvc.5.1.1** package and its satellites. They're the same...

I'm wondering if the problem could be on the NuGet server (but sounds weird to me)?

The server version is v2.8.50126.400

**UPDATE**
So it really seems to be the Server, as if I use a local path (C:...) as repo source, the packages act as expected.

Anyway I've just used the NuGet.Server package to create the server, there's some particular configuration I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the NuGet.Server .

There's a field missing during the serialization of the feed, the Language, that's why the official packages are working: on the official server the Language field IS serialized, that allow the NuGet client to move the resource assembly to the right folder under the main package's lib folder.

But on a private repository built with the NuGet.Server package this field is just missing.

I've applied a pull request on Codeplex, for the ones who have the same issue.

https://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/tanathos/nuget/contribution/6524